# Is it it cheating to share a quizlet?

Tags: cheating

I created a quizlet. Is it cheating to share it with classmates if it only contains material reviewed in the lectures? For context, we took a test on the material and the re-take for the test is coming up.

Comment: What do you mean by a quizlet? Is it just some practice questions you have created yourself, perhaps with answers?

Comment: Yes and definitions found in the lecture material. Quizlet is an online platform to create note cards to study from. By quizlet I mean a quizlet note card study set which is essentially online flash cards with some added features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly ethical to share such things. It is even ethical, in general, to discus such things in groups of students. I'd question any system in which the rules forbade such things.

But if you want to be maximally useful, share only the questions at first, not revealing the answers until others have a chance to work them out. It might then be useful to have a groups session in which you discuss the answers of different people to see if you agree.

Feedback is important to learning. In a group of students you can give feedback to one another. This helps the person getting it, but, in fact, also the one giving it.

There might be rules about sharing old exam questions, however, though it is impossible to enforce that and it is a rule often ignored, not just broken. No instructor would be wise to depend on such rules being honored.